can msdos partition be located past the 2TB point on a disk?
I have a 5 tb usb disk I use to copy a rhel-8.10.iso file to in order to install Linux.
In doing so the copy of that iso to /dev/sde creates an msdos partition table.  And it creates 2 partitions.
I just figured out how to use fdisk --type=msdos --wipe=never to create another partition  so that I can make an XFSpartition copy data to while preserving the bootable functionality to install RHEL.
fdisk recognizes the msdos partition and the 5tb total disk size, and warns in red text about msdos partition and the 2199023255552 limit (2tb).
I can create a 3rd and a 4th partition with fdisk ( preserving by bootable rhel8 install partition(s) )... my question is can I create partition #3 of 2TB in size and also a 4th partition also of 2TB in size to make the most out of my 5TB usb disk?
Is the msdos partition limit just that a given partition cannot exceed 2TB in size, or is it that the msdos partition table cannot address past the 2TB point of the disk to where from point 2.0001 TB to n TB will always not be usable?

Use gpt. Can you extract ISO into a 6GB FAT32 partition with boot & esp flags? I know some will directly boot from UEFI boot menu with just the extracted file using /efi/boot/bootx64.efi which is how all external drives boot.

i'd be happy to use GPT.  Problem is doing what you said, can it be done... i don't know.  Let me know what to type on the keyboard and i'll try.

Conversion from MBR(msdos) to gpt totally erases drive. If you have anything anywhere on drive, you want to keep, you must back it up to another device. You can use gparted from Ubuntu live installer. With gparted it is under the menu at top for device. You can use command line. sudo parted /dev/sdX mklabel gpt  where sdx is the drive like sda, sdb etc . Double check you have correct device by sudo parted -l first. Order of dev can change on reboot. From man fdisk  -# disk labels section:
"GPT is always a better choice than MBR, especially on modern hardware with a UEFI boot loader."

@oldfred MBR to GPT can be done without having to "totally erase [the] drive". If you have a partition immediately after the MBR, just resize it to start later and you can do the GPT conversion in place, no problem.

Gdisk also can convert in place with no guarantees. Or good backups still required. But every UUID & GUID changes, so if an install and not a data only drive, you have a lot of settings to edit. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html
gdisk to convert from gpt to MBR & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491478

thanks for the info, I might ask a separate question regarding this, if i decide on how much effort I want to put into this.

The 2 TiB limit applies to msdos partition tables as a whole: you can’t have a partition past 2 TiB. (As a consequence, you also can’t have partitions individually larger than 2 TiB.)
The limitation comes from the use of 32-bit values to encode sector numbers: the maximum number of sectors that can be addressed is thus 2³², i.e. 2 TiB using 512-byte sectors.

can a secondary partition table be used as a jump point (if I am wording that correctly) to make more partitions past the 2tb point on a large disk under the msdos partition scheme?  There is a basic limit of 4 partitions total, and I thought there was a way to do some extended partition table stuff to make many more partitions?  Can that be used to make subsequent 2tb partitions past my existing 2tb partition ?

That is indeed how extended partitions work, but they don’t allow the addresses to be shifted — logical partitions lie inside the extended partition, and the extended partition can’t extend past 2 TiB.
